# Sublime Text indentation behavior

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When using HTML syntax mode in Sublime Text, I see what appears to be erroneous behavior. However, I've exhausted Google trying to find any mention of the same issue. The image explains it best:

[image: Sublime indentation issue]

You'll note that in each instance, the cursor starts at the correct location (one tab in from the current tag). However, the indentation immediately shifts to the left when typing begins.

I've compared this behavior to Coda and Atom, but neither have this issue. Sublime Text 3 is up to date. The same behavior occurs with the default theme or a custom theme.

I realize there are shortcuts that can be used (div + tab + enter for example), but that doesn't help when editing an existing file where the elements are already present.

Any idea how to stop Sublime from unindenting like this?

Edit: Here is the contents of `Preferences > Settings - User`:

```
{
    "auto_match_enabled": false,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Spacegray/base16-ocean.dark.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 14,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "open_files_in_new_window": false,
    "theme": "Spacegray.sublime-theme",
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": false
}
```

Comment: Can you post your user preferences (**`Preferences -> Settings - User`**)? I'm having trouble replicating this...

Comment: Done. A friend of mine has also been able to replicate it. Sublime version is 3, build 3059.

Comment: Are you a registered user? If so, try downloading the latest [dev build](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev), which is 3062. For the life of me I can't replicate this, so it may have been fixed in this version.

Comment: Just registered and grabbed the latest dev version. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently asked a similar question at **[Sublime Text isn't indenting properly with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747915/sublime-text-isnt-indenting-properly-with-html).**

Try installing the [`Emmet`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) package. It allows you to write HTML in a much more efficient way, but also has its own indentation configuration. Typing `anytag`<kbd>Tab</kbd> gives you the properly indented text.

**An example without Emmet.**

[image: autoindentation problem in HTML]

**An example with Emmet.**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, misread the answer at first. Emmet does improve the original problem with its own indentation. I'll use it for now and since this is the only answer that actually works I'm marking it. Thanks :)