# Sublime Text isn't indenting properly with HTML

Tags: html, sublimetext2, indentation, auto-indent

**Related but not identical question: [Sublime Text indentation behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043158/sublime-text-indentation-behavior).**

I have seen many videos in which after the autocompletion of an HTML tag, pressing enter automatically results in the closing tag appearing two lines, and the cursor being properly indenting on the second line, between the opening and closing tabs.

In my situation, the autoindent function in Sublime Text 2 seems to be working poorly. Here is exactly what happens (as can be seen in the below gif).

[image: autoindenting problem in sublime text 2. The following list describes the exact problem.]

1. Press tab after writing tag to autocomplete the closing tag.
2. Press enter, which brings the closing tag one line.
3. Press enter again, which brings the closing tag onto the third line.
4. Press the up key to get to the second line.
5. Press the tab key again, which I would expect to properly indent, but instead, it brings me to the end of the closing tag on the third line.
6. Press the up key again to get to the second line again.
7. Press the tab key again, which finally indents the line properly.
8. Continue writing more HTML.

That is 7 keystrokes, which should under normal circumstances be 2 keystrokes. This applies to every tag I use in HTML, and it is getting extremely frustrating.

Note how this only happens in HTML. Below is a GIF of the autoindent function working properly (with only one keystroke) in CSS.

[image: autoindent function working perfectly fine in css. hitting tab once creates three lines, with the cursor properly indented on the second line.]

I have very few, unrelated packages installed on ST2. Here are the contents of my **Settings - User** file.

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Spacegray/base16-ocean.dark.tmTheme",
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "theme": "Spacegray.sublime-theme",
    "margin": 0,
    "fold_buttons": false,
    "draw_minimap_border": true,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false
}
```

**Why does my autoindent function in Sublime Text 2 do this? And how can I fix it?**

**EDIT:** @Shomz has indicated that this is how HTML indenting works by default. Is there any plugin/workaround I can use to get the desired effect?

Comment: Have you enabled auto_indent and smart_indent?

Comment: The power of Sublime is in its customizability, you can easily create your own autocompletion rules or try to find a good plugin. Or you can wait for someone to post one here. But yeah, that's how it works for HTML by default.

Comment: @emzy both smart_indent and auto_indent are turned on by default, and I haven't changed them in my user settings.

Comment: @Shomz Thanks for the input. Seems a little ridiculous for it to be this way by default... Hoping to get a plugin recommendation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the [`Emmet`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) plugin, previously known as Zen Coding. It allows you to enter HTML using a CSS selector-like syntax, so for example

```
html>body>div.main
```

and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> gives you

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="main">|</div>
</body>
</html>
```

where the `|` is the cursor position. More importantly, for your present question, just typing `body`<kbd>Tab</kbd> gives you

```
<body>
    |
</body>
```

just like you were looking for. See the [Emmet docs](http://docs.emmet.io/) for all the details.

Comment: I was aware of Emmet previously, but didn't realize it would fix my indentation problem when writing HTML "normally". This works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine yeah, the default HTML package (like a number of default Sublime packages) has some issues, and is a bit outdated when it comes to HTML5. Emmet has a bit of a learning curve when it comes to really powerful expressions (try `#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a{Item $}`, for example), but once you get used to it it's a great help.